# assigning values to IntVar if and only if BoolVar, else zero [or-tools]

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, c++

If I have an  `IntVar` `s[j]` stored in a vector `s`, is it possible to iterate for (a period of time) `t` and create a `BoolVar` `b` such that `b[t]` is true if and only if `s[j]==t`? I tried setting some restrictions:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < nbTasks; ++j)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < tmax; ++t)
        {
            const IntVar expr = cp_model.NewIntVar(Domain(-1000000000,100000000000));
            const IntVar actual_t = cp_model.NewConstant(t).WithName("actual_t");
            const BoolVar b = cp_model.NewBoolVar().WithName("b");
            const IntVar value = cp_model.NewConstant(w[j][t]);

            obj_final.push_back(expr);
            actuals[j].push_back(actual_t);
            expressions[j].push_back(expr);
            values[j].push_back(value);

            cp_model.AddEquality(b, starts[j]==actual_t);
            cp_model.AddProductEquality(expr, {value, b});
        }
    }
```

I created the `BoolVar` `b` and then set an equality to the bool value of `s[j]==t`, then I used the constraint `expr == value*b` and added the expression to the vector `obj_final`, and finally set the objective: `cp_model.Maximize(LinearExpr::Sum(obj_final));` The problem is that my solution is optimal but the objective is zero, so I guess `b` is always false.

My goal is to assign a value to an expression if and only if `s[j]==t`. Enforce constraints isn't what i need because the other expressions must be zero. 
I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: You should read this: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that `OnlyEnforceIf` takes only `BoolVar` as argument, and the condition i need (`s[j]==t`) is just `bool` , i tried but the function don't match the argument.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't what you want: `cp_model.AddEquality(s[j], t).OnlyEnforceIf(b)` and `cp_model.AddEquality(s[j], 0).OnlyEnforceIf(Not(b))` ? Which is more or less the same as the example linked

Comment: Nope, i want to `cp_model.AddEquality(expr, value).OnlyEnforceIf(s[j]==t)`  but `OnlyEnforceIf` takes only `BoolVar` arguments and not `bool` (as s[j]==t). So i want to create a `BoolVar` that is true if `s[j]==t`, else false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an intermediate boolean that is true iff `s[j] == t` you just have to create 2 constraints:

```
cp_model.AddEquality(s[j], t).OnlyEnforceIf(b);
cp_model.AddNotEqual(s[j], t).OnlyEnforceIf(Not(b));
```

The problem with this line:

```
cp_model.AddEquality(b, starts[j]==actual_t);
```

is that `starts[j]==actual_t` "always" evaluates to false.

To learn more about channeling, see:

- https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md
- https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/integer_arithmetic.md#step-function

Comment: Thanks! its solving. I'm modelling an RCPSP with discount rate (precomputed and rounded) do you think that it is the best way to model it?

Comment: I am no expert in that, sorry. It might be better to ask a new question explaining your model so people can comment on it